# Fixing memory leaks in my first app

Tags: iphone, xcode4

People of the Stack Overflow I need your help. I am about to publish my first app ever to the App Store and I need help fixing the memory leaks my app has. Its a simple view based application with multiple views, iAds, and buttons with sounds (The app is a simple sound board).I would need examples of what exactly I should put and a picture of where

Analyzer message: `Potential Leak of an Object allocated on Line 135 and stored into 'soundFileURLRef'`

```
-(IBAction)sound25 {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"BELLMACH", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);

    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Comment: First run the Analyzer.  With Xcode 3 that's "Build" then "Build and Analyze".  With Xcode 4 it's "Product", then "Analyze".

Comment: Ok i did that and it says this

Comment: Potential Leak of an Object allocated on Line 135 and stored into 'soundFileURLRef'

Comment: Well, look at line 135 and see what's there.  Or you could even post your source here (the relevant parts thereof) so we could look at it and help you.

Comment: http://codepad.org/WvBshpRS    heres a link to the code line. Its like this for 24 sounds because the app i have is a sound board.

Comment: That code doesn't seem to be related.  And you can include the code inline in your post above by editing the post, pasting the code in, selecting it, and pressing the `{}` icon above the edit window.

Comment: OK, I pasted it in for you.  Presumably line 135 is the 4th line above.

Comment: You have to add `CFRelease (soundFileURLRef)` at the end to release your reference. Copying an object always retains the new value ;)

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for `CFBundleCopyResourceURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html) says that it follows the ["Create Rule"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029), which in turn basically says that any function with "create" or "copy" in its name returns a retained object. You have ownership of this object until you're done with it - it's therefore your responsibility to call `CFRelease` on the object when you have no further use for it. Presumably, that's after you use it to create and play a system sound, so you could just add

```
CFRelease(soundFileURLRef);
```

at the end of that method and be OK, assuming you don't hang on to or need `soundFileURLRef` for anywhere else.

Comment: I did analyze after I put in that code. Thank you all so much.

Comment: You're welcome! If you like one of these answers, you should consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Since the name "CFBundleCopyResourceURL" contains the word "Copy", it follows the "create rule" and you "own" the object and are responsible for releasing it when you're done with it.